# Brute force solution returns wrong answer for Project Euler problem 31

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with [Project Euler problem 31](https://projecteuler.net/problem=31). 
The correct answer is 73,682, and my answer is 73,681.
Here is the problem:

> In the United Kingdom the currency is made up of pound (£) and pence (p). There are eight coins in general circulation:
>   1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, £1 (100p), and £2 (200p).
>
> It is possible to make £2 in the following way:
>   1×£1 + 1×50p + 2×20p + 1×5p + 1×2p + 3×1p.
>
> How many different ways can £2 be made using any number of coins?

And my code:

```py
counter = 0
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(5):
        if 100 * a + 50 * b > 200:
            break
        for c in range(11):
            if 100 * a + 50 * b + 20 * c > 200:
                break
            for d in range(21):
                if 100 * a + 50 * b + 20 * c + 10 * d > 200:
                    break
                for e in range(41):
                    if 100 * a + 50 * b + 20 * c + 10 * d  + 5 * e > 200:
                        break
                    for f in range(101):
                        if 100 * a + 50 * b + 20 * c + 10 * d + 5 * e + 2 * f <= 200:
                            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: Your solution is off by 1; it looks like you simply missed the case where you can use a £2 coin and nothing else.

Comment: for matching different ways you can use ```itertools``` module and see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: @kaya3 is right, you don't have "200 * X" anywhere in the code. But instead of adding a loop for that, just start `counter` at one and you're good. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code doesn't consider the case where you just have a £2 coin. You can just initialize the variable `counter` to 1 to fix this issue.